# Saving data in Recycle View Edit_Text

Tags: android

[image] In `RecycleView` from right side it has `Edit_text` when user changes dummy data in `Edit_text` it should be saved in `Edit_text` even when list row goes up/down from the view or by pressing switch button user goes to other view.   I want to save data in `Edit_Text`

For this I have implemented `RecycleView`,Adapter classes and developed a Simple Loader class.

I am fetching data from Loader class into my `RecycleView` Class and sending data into adapter class.
After getting data from Adapter class Edit_Text I am sending data back to Loader Class for Saving.

But when I change data in `Edit_Text` it does not save. Kindly cooperate.
`RecycleView` Class `OnCreate` Method:

```
   // Dummy Data
String[] mobileArray = {"Android", "Skype", "mail", "twitter", "What's app", "facebook", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Android", "IPhone", "WindowsMobile"};
int[] programImages = { R.drawable.ic_phone,R.drawable.ic_skype,R.drawable.ic_email, R.drawable.ic_twitter, R.drawable.ic_whatsapp, R.drawable.ic_facebook,
        R.drawable.check_icon, R.drawable.check_icon, R.drawable.check_icon, R.drawable.check_icon, R.drawable.check_icon};


String[] data = {"Android", "Skype", "mail", "twitter", "What's app", "Ubuntu", "Windows7","koki","Andreas","Niko","Filip"};

//Getting EditText data From Loader class

String [] numbers=new DataLoader().getFirstdata();
String [] statics=new DataLoader().getSeconddata();


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);


        //Recycle View

    final RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha)));



    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomRecycleAdapter(programImages,mobileArray,numbers));



    //In Switch I am changing the data in Adapter


    mySwitch.setChecked(true);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomRecycleAdapter(programImages,mobileArray,numbers));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch is checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomRecycleAdapter(programImages,data,statics));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch is not checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
    public class CustomRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

String [] result;
int [] imageId;
String [] numbers;
Context context;

// Loader object
DataLoader loader=new DataLoader();

LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    EditText editText;
    TextView title;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        image=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_list_icon);
        editText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.number);

    }
}


public CustomRecycleAdapter(int[] programImages, String[] mobileArray, String[] numbers) {

    //  this.context=context;
    imageId=programImages;
    result=mobileArray;




    this.numbers=numbers;


}

@Override
public CustomRecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_profile_list, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomRecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(result[position]);
    holder.editText.setText(numbers[position]);
    holder.image.setImageResource(imageId[position]);




    // Loader getting Edited Text


    loader.setFirstdata(position,holder.editText.getText().toString());
    numbers[position]=holder.editText.getText().toString();

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return result.length;
 }

}
```

My Loader Class:

```
public class DataLoader {


String[] numbers = {"+4312345678", "aaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbb", "+9255433654", "567567", "342245", "6545645", "456546", "123123", "324234", "1455433654"};

String[] statics = {"+4312345678", "ddddddddd", "kkkkkkkkkkk", "+9255433654", "567567", "0098", "+=0909", "++8883","+4312345678", "ssssss", "tttttttttttt"};



public void setFirstdata(int position, String data){
    numbers[position]=data;
}
public void setSecondData(int position, String data){
    statics[position]=data;
}

public String[] getFirstdata(){
    return numbers;
}
public String[] getSeconddata(){
    return statics;
}

}
```

Comment: "if i move to other view still I should get the edited data" I'm unclear what this means. Please provide a step-by-step example of what the user does and what behavior you want your app to have. Be as specific as you can. Rather than "User enteres text" give an actual example of what the user will type.

Comment: User change data in Edit_text and if he/she moves to other View and comes back then data displayed in Edite_Text should be the changed one(that user did) not the initial one.

Comment: Fill in the blanks: 1. The EditText originally has _____ as its text. 2. The user taps on the EditText and types _____. 3. Then the user _____. Continue from there. (This is what **be specific** means.) Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: 1. Dummy Data.  2. String    3. Other View or List moves up/down.

Comment: What part of "be specific" do you not understand?

Comment: I am sorry but what should I explain more ?

Comment: Yes. Be specific means "explain more". It also means give a specific example. What **exactly** is in the EditText originally? What **exactly** does the user type in? What **exactly** does the user do next, step by step?

Comment: Recycle View has Edit_Text when User change data in Edit_text it should be saved in Loader class when Recycle view is moved up/down or when user comes back from other view the Edit_text shows changed data not dummy data.

Comment: That's still not specific. What **exact** text is in the EditText, as an example?

Comment: Edit_Text Initially has:  Dummy data     User Edits it:  Now Edit_Text must display data changed by User not the dummy one/initial one.

Comment: So it has the letters "Dummy data"? Exactly word for word?

Comment: What does the user type after that?

Comment: User types Any String.

Comment: Again... **be specific** "any string" is **not** specific.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120726/discussion-between-shahek-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: Can you Plz tell me something about this ?

Comment: I will be glad to help you when you provide the details I have asked for.

Comment: Thanks and come in chat Plz I would be happy to share details.

Comment: I am busy at the moment. Please edit your original question to include the details I have asked for. I or someone else will help you from there.

Comment: If you would like more details Plz let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**@Shahek** there is two tips for you first don't create three types of array simply create a model Class for storing your data.

```
   public void YourModelClass {
      String result;
      int  imageId;
      String numbers;

    public YourModelClass(String result,int imageId,String number){
        this.result = result;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.number = number

    }
  }
```

and create a `List<YourModelClass>` and then your Adapter Constructor look like

```
public CustomRecycleAdapter(List<YourModelClass> yourModelList) {
    this.yourModelList  = yourModelList;
}
```

and

create a seperate method for updating `editText` and whenever you update a field you have to `notifyAdapter` which you didn't call

```
private void updateListItemAtPos(int position){
   loader.setFirstdata(position,holder.editText.getText().toString());
    numbers[position]=holder.editText.getText().toString();
}
```

you only have to update List item and call notify and RecyclerView automatically saved the edited text